# Is the Eclipse SonarQube plugin compatible with Eclipse Mars?

Tags: eclipse, sonarqube

I cannot install SonarQube plugins in Eclipse Mars (tested with Java, RCP and Modeling versions).

When I search for SonarQube in 'Help' / 'Eclipse Marketplace' then the result list is *empty*. I can click at the link 'Browse for more solutions' which opens the marketplace site on the internet. There, I see SonarQube with the link 'Install' but when I click on it I get the error "The following solutions (SonarQube) are not compatible with this version of Eclipse"!

Any ideas how the problem can be solved?

Comment: Ticket created @Andreas to make sure that the next 3.5 version of the Eclipse SonarQube plugin will be compatible and defined as being compatible in the eclipse marketplace : http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCLIPS-446

Comment: I have updated Marketplace metadata. Should be available now.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse SonarQube plugin 3.4 is definitely compatible with Eclipse Mars.

Unfortunately, you cannot install it from the Eclipse Marketplace - probably because we need to update the compatibility information there. As mentionned by Freddy in his comment, [SONARCLIPS-446](http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARCLIPS-446) was created for this purpose.

Meanwhile, please follow the instructions described on ["Install SonarQube in Eclipse"](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) to manually install the plugin.

**UPDATE July 21rst, 2015**: the Marketplace has been updated so anybody using Mars can install the plugin through the Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but SonarQube is not really compatible.

If you install SonarQube 3.4.0 from marketplace to a brand new mars (eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64.zip) and then start the eclispe with -clean, the menuitem marketplace is gone.

Seems that there are not some other plugins don't match.

See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=473495